# get gridview data of each cell of each row as variables from a webusercontrol to webform in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to get gridview values of each cell of each row as variables which are displayed using webusercontrol on a webform in asp.net
i tried this but it isn't working,

```
Control control1 = null;
GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.FindControl("GridView");

foreach (GridViewRow row1 in GridView1.Rows)
{
   control1 = GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0];
   string Price = (control1.FindControl("Price") as Label).Text;
   string Quantity = (control1.FindControl("Quantity") as Label).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already looping all `GridViewRows`, these are the controls which are the `NamingContainers` of your labels in the `ItemTemplate` which you can find with `row.FindControl`:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
   Label lblPrice = (Label)row.FindControl("Price");
   string Price = lblPrice.Text;
   Label lblQuantity = (Label)row.FindControl("Quantity");
   string Quantity = lblQuantity.Text;
}
```

Comment: actually i need to get it from web user control,                                    GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.FindControl("GridView");   Is it correct ?

Comment: @HimadriVarshney: no, why don't you access `GridView` directly? `GridView GridView1 = this.GridView`? Confusing. But the question was about the loop and how you try to find your labels which of course doesn't work that way or is at least very strange. What is the error you get and where?

Comment: i can't use it directly because gridview is in web user control and i have to use it on another web form

Comment: @HimadriVarshney: the best way to access a control from a UserControl from within a Page is to provide a property in your UserControl thast returns it. On that way you keep compikle time safety and you could even change the ID of your grid without breaking any code.